# How to generate the hash in base64 for ds:DigestValue, ds:SignatureValue and ds:X509Certificate using python?

Tags: python, xml

I need to generate and sign an XML. **I'm using Windows 10**.

I've a certificate in PFX format (also known as P12). I've succesfully extracted the key and cert from that file, in order to sign an XML.

**But now I need to know how to sign that XML? More exactly, how to generate the content for this XMl elements:** `ds:DigestValue`, `ds:SignatureValue` and `ds:X509Certificate`???

According to the documentation of the entity that will verify the signed XML, this elements are:

**ds:SignatureValue**: contains the base64 coded sign. The sign is the result of a series of transformations over the binari data of the element `<ds:SignedInfo>`. The element `<ds:SignatureValue>` contains this binari value of the coded sign in `base64`.

**ds:DigestMethod**: defines the hash function to be used, through the Algorithm atribute.

**ds: DigestValue**: Is the hash value in `base64`.

**ds:X509Certificate**: it is just the sign.

The final XML has other parts that holds different information, but I like to understand how to construct the mentioned tags:

```
<ds:Signature Id="IDSignSA">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#envelopedsignature"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>X4V0Z4K8CNcrud9vojN Iy/8hjkk=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>U8bSaZUgOiD F3VDtwFRPiZ/6AQkSht7ezF8QVv+g5ELiLqkQHmRoL7VMLUtaHr+A9VhkIb5RZU5P EoRcvxI9v37zJg2WUe2wpKAY7AHm7kvvUHEs09K8Q+c0rqNaAAK1kvXPHbVFXnn0o2oLWI1bI/rS sWsFtjdmVtyLjkDEzf8=</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509SubjectName>1. 2.840.113549.1.9.1=#161a4253554c434140534f55544845524e504552552e434f4d2e5045,CN=Pedro Solano,OU=10261110983,O=SOLANO ALMAGRO PEDRO,L=TACNA,ST=TACNA,C=PE</ds:X509SubjectName>
            <ds:X509Certificate>MIIESTCCAzGgAwIBAgI
KWOCRzgAAAAAAIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAnMRUwEwYKCZImiZPyLGQB
GRYFU1VOQVQxDjAMBgNVBAMTBVNVTkFUMB4XDTEwMTIyODE5NTExMFoXDTExMTIyODIwMDExMFow
gZUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlBFMQ0wCwYDVQQIEwRMSU1BMQ0wCwYDVQQHEwRMSU1BMREwDwYDVQQKEwhT
T1VUSEVSTjEUMBIGA1UECxMLMjAxMDAxNDc1MTQxFDASBgNVBAMTC0JvcmlzIFN1bGNhMSkwJwYJ
KoZIhvcNAQkBFhpCU1VMQ0FAU09VVEhFUk5QRVJVLkNPTS5QRTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOB
jQAwgYkCgYEAtRtcpfBLzyajuEmYt4mVH8EE02KQiETsdKStUThVYM7g3Lkx5zq3SH5nLH00EKGC
tota6RR+V40sgIbnh+Nfs1SOQcAohNwRfWhho7sKNZFR971rFxj4cTKMEvpt8Dr98UYFkJhph6Wn
sniGM2tJDq9KJ52UXrlScMfBityx0AsCAwEAAaOCAYowggGGMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIE8DBEBgkq
hkiG9w0BCQ8ENzA1MA4GCCqGSIb3DQMCAgIAgDAOBggqhkiG9w0DBAICAIAwBwYFKw4DAgcwCgYI
KoZIhvcNAwcwHQYDVR0OBBYEFG/m6twbiRNzRINavjq+U0j/sZECMBMGA1UdJQQMMAoGCCsGAQUF
BwMCMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFN9kHQDqWONmozw3xdNSIMFW2t+7MFkGA1UdHwRSMFAwTqBMoEqGImh0
dHA6Ly9wY2IyMjYvQ2VydEVucm9sbC9TVU5BVC5jcmyGJGZpbGU6Ly9cXHBjYjIyNlxDZXJ0RW5y
b2xsXFNVTkFULmNybDB+BggrBgEFBQcBAQRyMHAwNQYIKwYBBQUHMAKGKWh0dHA6Ly9wY2IyMjYv
Q2VydEVucm9sbC9wY2IyMjZfU1VOQVQuY3J0MDcGCCsGAQUFBzAChitmaWxlOi8vXFxwY2IyMjZc
Q2VydEVucm9sbFxwY2IyMjZfU1VOQVQuY3J0MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQBI6wJ/QmRpz3C3
rorBflOvA9DOa3GNiiB7rtPIjF4mPmtgfo2pK9gvnxmV2pST3ovfu0nbG2kpjzzaaelRjEodHvkc
M3abGsOE53wfxqQF5uf/jkzZA9hbLHtE1aLKBD0Mhzc6cvI072alnE6QU3RZ16ie9CYsHmMrs+sP
HMy8DJU5YrdnqHdSn2D3nhKBi4QfT/WURPOuo6DF4iWgrCyMf3eJgmGKSUN3At5fK4HSpfyURT0k
boaJKNBgQwy0HhGh5BLM7DsTi/KwfdUYkoFgrY71Pm23+ra+xTow1Vk9gj5NqrlpMY5gAVQXEIo1
++GxDtaK/5EiVKSqzJ6geIfz</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>

<cac:Signature>
    <cbc:ID>IDSignSA</cbc:ID>
    <cac:SignatoryParty>
        <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID>10261110983</cbc:ID>
        </cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>SOLANO ALMAGRO PEDRO</cbc:Name>
        </cac:PartyName>
    </cac:SignatoryParty>
    <cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
        <cac:ExternalReference>
            <cbc:URI>#signature</cbc:URI>
        </cac:ExternalReference>
    </cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
</cac:Signature>
```

I've found the `signxml` library. And it has an example:

```
from lxml import etree
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier

data_to_sign = "<Test/>"
cert = open("example.pem").read()
key = open("example.key").read()
root = etree.fromstring(data_to_sign)
signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root).signed_xml
```

**But would this example generate the contents for the 3 tags?**

**UPDATE 1:**

I've tried to put my XML like this to sign it but getting an error:

```
from lxml import etree
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier



passwd = 'caballo123'
cd = 'D:\\facturacion_electronica\\cetificado_prueba\\'


my_data_to_sign = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
    xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" 
    xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" 
    xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1" 
    xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <sac:AdditionalInformation>
                    <sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
                        <cbc:ID>1001</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">1407.29</cbc:PayableAmount>
                    </sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
                    <sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
                        <cbc:ID>1004</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">48.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
                    </sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
                    <sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
                        <cbc:ID>2005</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">74.07</cbc:PayableAmount>
                    </sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
                    <sac:AdditionalProperty>
                        <cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:Value>SON MIL SEISCIENTOS SESENTA Y 60/100</cbc:Value>
                    </sac:AdditionalProperty>
                </sac:AdditionalInformation>
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <ds:Signature Id="signatureKG">
                    <ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                        <ds:Reference URI="">
                            <ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#envelopedsignature"/>
                            </ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                            <ds:DigestValue></ds:DigestValue>
                        </ds:Reference>
                    </ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:SignatureValue></ds:SignatureValue>
                    <ds:KeyInfo>
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509SubjectName>1.2 .840.113549.1.9.1=#161a4253554c434140534f55544845524e504552552e434f4d2e5045,CN=Carlos Vega,OU=10200545523,O=Vega Poblete Carlos Enrique,L=CHICLAYO,ST=LAMBAYEQUE,C=PE</ds:X509SubjectName>
                            <ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Certificate>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                </ds:Signature>
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:CustomizationID>1.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ID>BC01-3652</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2012-06-24</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>03</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>PEN</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cac:Signature>
        <cbc:ID>IDSignKG</cbc:ID>
        <cac:SignatoryParty>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>10200545523</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>VEGA POBLETE CARLOS ENRIQUE</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
        </cac:SignatoryParty>
        <cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
            <cac:ExternalReference>
                <cbc:URI>#SignatureKG</cbc:URI>
            </cac:ExternalReference>
        </cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
    </cac:Signature>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID>10200545523</cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID>
        <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>6</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>ELECTRODOMESTICOS CRUZ DE MOTUPE</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:ID>140106</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:StreetName>AV. LOS TALLANES #235</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>URB. MIGUEL GRAU</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>CHICLAYO</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:CountrySubentity>LAMBAYEQUE</cbc:CountrySubentity>
                <cbc:District>LA VICTORIA</cbc:District>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>PE</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>VEGA POBLETE CARLOS ENRIQUE</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID>00078647</cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID>
        <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>SOLEDAD ASUNCION CARRASCO PEREZ</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">253.31</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">253.31</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
                    <cbc:Name>IGV</cbc:Name>
                    <cbc:TaxTypeCode>VAT</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">1660.60</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="NIU">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="PEN">845.76</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:PricingReference>
            <cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">998.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
                <cbc:PriceTypeCode>01</cbc:PriceTypeCode>
            </cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
        </cac:PricingReference>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">152.24</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">152.24</cbc:TaxAmount>
                <cac:TaxCategory>
                    <cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>10</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:Name>IGV</cbc:Name>
                        <cbc:TaxTypeCode>VAT</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:TaxCategory>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Description>Refrigeradora marca "AXM" no frost de 200 ltrs</cbc:Description>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>REF564</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">845.76</cbc:PriceAmount>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="NIU">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="PEN">635.59</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:PricingReference>
            <cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">750.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
                <cbc:PriceTypeCode>01</cbc:PriceTypeCode>
            </cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
        </cac:PricingReference>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">114.41</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">114.41</cbc:TaxAmount>
                <cac:TaxCategory>
                    <cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>10</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:Name>IGV</cbc:Name>
                        <cbc:TaxTypeCode>VAT</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:TaxCategory>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Description>Cocina a gas GLP, marca "AXM" de 5 hornillas</cbc:Description>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>COC124</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">635.59</cbc:PriceAmount>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="NIU">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:PricingReference>
            <cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
                <cbc:PriceTypeCode>01</cbc:PriceTypeCode>
            </cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
            <cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">4.80</cbc:PriceAmount>
                <cbc:PriceTypeCode>02</cbc:PriceTypeCode>
            </cac:AlternativeConditionPrice>
        </cac:PricingReference>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
                <cac:TaxCategory>
                    <cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>31</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>1000</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:Name>IGV</cbc:Name>
                        <cbc:TaxTypeCode>VAT</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:TaxCategory>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Description>Sixpack de gaseosa "Guaraná" de 400 ml.</cbc:Description>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>NOB012</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
'''


data_to_sign = my_data_to_sign
cert = open("llama_cert.pem").read()
key = open("llama.key").read()
root = etree.fromstring(data_to_sign)
signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root, x509_cert=cert).signed_xml
print(verified_data)
```

Comment: "Buy" -> "But". Have you *tried*? I'd think that the digest and signature value are not optional in the DigSig documentation, right? If one or more X509 certificates are included is rather a better question, as those values are optional.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica yes, I've tried to put all my XML, with the 3 tags empty, but when running the code I get: `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document, line 2, column 6`. I'll my answer to show.

Comment: That document seems to have been already signed. Namespaces in XML (signature generation) are a complete PITA, so that might pose a problem. And badly designed XML digsig libraries may even be fooled by accepting bad signatures etc.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica I've deleted the contents of the 3 tags, but my idea is to genrate the XML from scratch, so If you think I need to delete something else to avoid troubles, let me know pls.

Comment: try to remove xml declaration line -<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>.  lxml seem to complain on strings with xml declaration

Comment: @Alexander but the model XML has that declaration. I need the output to be identical.